# Facebook iOS SDK 3.x feed dialog is gone?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Today I started to use [Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/) and I realized that there is no **FBDialog** class anymore. I've searched **developers.facebook.com** for some tutorials how I can show feed dialog using new sdk.

We used to write:

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But, it seems that all tips talking about dialogs are related to old SDK in **developers.facebook.com**.

Did anybody implemented feed dialog with new SDK?

Or, should we build our own `DialogViewController` to represent all UI elements as textFields, send button in order to make [FBRequest](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdk-reference/iossdk/3.0/class/FBRequest/)?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the answer here:
[Feed Dialog - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/)

Using the same new SDK 3.x we must add **deprecated headers** into Frameworks:
[image]
[image]
 and change:

`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`

to

`#import "Facebook.h"`

**EDIT (26.02.2013):**

Thanks to [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44014/andreas), he mentioned in comment, using new **SDK 3.2** doesn't required you include deprecated classes anymore:

> Improved Web dialog support: This release adds support for integrating
>   Web dialogs, [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), and [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), without invoking
>   deprecated headers, making it cleaner and easier to add dialogs into
>   your app.

**Example:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"", @"name",
     @"", @"caption",
     @"", @"description",
     @"https://website.com/share", @"link",
     @"http://website.com/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
         ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
                 NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
             } else {
                 if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                     // User clicked the "x" icon
                     NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 } else {
                     // Handle the publish feed callback
                 }
             }
        }];
```

Comment: Is there no new way to invoke a dialog concept that isn't deprecated? I'm personally fine with massaging my own code to work with their newer techniques but yeah I still want to get a dialog preview of what is to be submitted by my app.

Comment: @Joey Facebook recommends the way I've described above. I think it's the only way.

Comment: Anyone knows until when is this gonna be available?

Comment: I did what Facebook says, but I get duplicated symbols, because they are on FacebookSDK.h and Facebook.h

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as estemendoza. Duplicate symbols.  Did we do something wrong?

Comment: Found the problem. Seems I was including the FacebookSDK header in one of my header files. Make sure you are not including this anywhere in your source.

Comment: What i do not get is according to https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013, posting to friends wall with GraphApi will be unavalaible by 06.02.2013 and the yadvice me to use feed dialog which is deprecated in SDK 3.1???

Comment: Yesterday, FacebookSDK 3.2 was released, which doesn't require you to pull in deprecated headers anymore. Quoting the changelog: "This release adds support for integrating web dialogs, Feed Dialog and Requests Dialog, without invoking deprecated headers making it cleaner and easier to add dialogs into your app."

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek Can you please clarify me regarding posting to friends wall on their birthday,in your above code I don't see any specification of where to post,when to post etc.??

Answer (score 3):

With Facebook SDK 3.2, you don't need to import deprecated headers anymore. Web-based dialogs can be presented using the FBWebDialogs class:

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```