# Post on wall using ios facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

In my ios app I want to post on the user wall using facebookSDK 3.1.
in addition i would like to avoid using permissions if posible.

Comment: You cannot post to a user's wall without him giving you permission to do so.

Comment: I thought about using facebook dialogs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GraphAPI 
From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               kAppId, @"app_id",
                               @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                               @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                               @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for apps to interact with users.", @"description",
                               @"Facebook Dialogs are so easy!",  @"message",
                               nil];

[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: what is the type of _facebook?

Comment: @user1746700 its graph api

Comment: how do I declare _facebook varialbe?

Comment: its the object of Facebook class.
Facebook    *_facebook;

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I didn't find Facebook object in my sdk
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122098/facebook-ios-sdk-3-x-feed-dialog-is-gone
Help me to add it